# Show results on Jtable between dates when selected Jdatechooser (Mysql)

Tags: java, mysql, swing

This is the query for the (between dates). But when I select the dates and click OK all records on `JTable` disappears. Help me to build the query and statement for the get record between dates on `JTable`.

[Jtable with records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT6uJ.png)

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here

    // java.util.Date val1 = jDateChooser1.getDate();


    // java.util.Date val2 = jDateChooser2.getDate();


    java.sql.Date val1 = new java.sql.Date(jDateChooser1.getDate().getTime());

    java.sql.Date val2 = new java.sql.Date(jDateChooser2.getDate().getTime());

    try {

        String sql = "select * from Umar where Date between ? and ? ";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setDate(1, val1);
        pst.setDate(2, val2);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    } catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't have access to your database. We don't know what dates your are using for the select statement. Does your database hold actual Date objects, or just the toString() representation of a Date. It is up to YOU to do some basic debugging. Display the values of vale1/val2. Display the row/columns of the table. First get the SQL to work by hardcoding the dates you want to use. Then once that works you make the code dynamic. Basically you need to learn how to debug your own problems!!!

Comment: @camickr please check the image sir dates format are yyyy-mm-dd and  are choosing from jdatechooser

Comment: It doesn't matter what the dates are in the JTable. You are building an SQL query. Your need to do the query in the format the data in stored in your database. Since we don't know how the data was created and stored in your database we can't tell you how to build the data. Again, the table is irrelevant to the question. The question is about getting data returned in the ResultSet. So create a simple class with a hard coded SQL query. Read the suggestion given!!!

Comment: :(                                  can you tell the query and statement after watch mine

Answer (score 1):

Once again we know nothing about your database. It is up to you to know how the data is displayed in the database.

Here is a simple query to get you started.

```
String sql = "Select * from Umar";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement();
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery( sql );
ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
int columns = md.getColumnCount();

//  Get column names

for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
{
    System.out.println( md.getColumnLabel(i) );
}

//  Get row data

while (rs.next())
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
    {
        Object data = rs.getObject(I);
        System.out.println(data + " : " + data.getClass());
    }
}

rs.close();
stmt.close();
```

This has absolutely nothing to do with your JTable. It is just a query of the database. So get this query working. Determine how the date is stored in your database. Is it a String or a Date?

Then next you change the query:

```
String sql = "Select * from Umar where Date between ? and ? ";
...
ps.setDate/String(1, ...);
ps.setDate/String(2, ...);
```

Then you test this with a hard coded data to make sure you get data. Then once this step is working you fix your program that loads the data into the JTable.